# iOS - 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode, duplicates, linker-errors

I am having an issue understanding a linker command error. I am receiving the following:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_XYZAddToDoItemViewController._toDoItem in:
/Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoToday-fjyijxlbvauebmeuhtgdvdrjtfez/Build/Intermediates/ToDoToday.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ToDoToday.build/Objects-normal/i386/XYZToDoListViewController.o
/Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoToday-fjyijxlbvauebmeuhtgdvdrjtfez/Build/Intermediates/ToDoToday.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ToDoToday.build/Objects-normal/i386/XYZAddToDoItemViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_XYZAddToDoItemViewController in:
/Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoToday-fjyijxlbvauebmeuhtgdvdrjtfez/Build/Intermediates/ToDoToday.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ToDoToday.build/Objects-normal/i386/XYZToDoListViewController.o
/Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoToday-fjyijxlbvauebmeuhtgdvdrjtfez/Build/Intermediates/ToDoToday.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ToDoToday.build/Objects-normal/i386/XYZAddToDoItemViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_XYZAddToDoItemViewController in:
/Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoToday-fjyijxlbvauebmeuhtgdvdrjtfez/Build/Intermediates/ToDoToday.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ToDoToday.build/Objects-normal/i386/XYZToDoListViewController.o
/Users/*/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ToDoToday-fjyijxlbvauebmeuhtgdvdrjtfez/Build/Intermediates/ToDoToday.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ToDoToday.build/Objects-normal/i386/XYZAddToDoItemViewController.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not sure which symbols Xcode is referring to exactly. Below are the top of the implementation files.

XYZToDoListViewController.m:

```
#import "XYZAddToDoItemViewController.h"
@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController ()
@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;
@end
@implementation XYZAddToDoItemViewController
```

XYZAddToDoItemViewController.m:

```
#import "XYZAddToDoItemViewController.h"
@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
@end
@implementation XYZAddToDoItemViewController
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `XYZToDoListViewController.m` change:

```
@interface XYZAddToDoItemViewController ()
```

to:

```
@interface XYZToDoListViewController ()
```

and:

```
@implementation XYZAddToDoItemViewController
```

to:

```
@implementation XYZToDoListViewController
```

and:

```
#import "XYZAddToDoItemViewController.h"
```

to:

```
#import "XYZToDoListViewController.h"
```

Basically you have the wrong class name in the `XYZToDoListViewController.m` file.

Make you don't have the same mistake in the `XYZToDoListViewController.h` file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately when I do that I receive 13 new errors, among them "cannot find interface declaration for XYZToDoListViewController", "class XYZToDoListViewController defined without specifying a base class", and many properties not found.

Comment: Look at what you posted in your question. Both .m files incorrectly reference the same class name. It looks like a copy/paste error. Either in your actual code or in what you posted in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed a few more things in the implementation files and I was able to get it to build without error.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this error when I import A.m in B.m

Make sure you only import .h files