# How to fix "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I was solving some conflict issues in Xcode, but when I run the application it returned these error messages:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_MessagesViewController._users in:
    /Users/BrenoMorais/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimplyCircle-fbtbskibjbfgzofjcvomrqorcxuq/Build/Intermediates/SimplyCircle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SimplyCircle.build/Objects-normal/i386/MessagesViewController-8AA2A9C32D34C91E.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_MessagesViewController in:
    /Users/BrenoMorais/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimplyCircle-fbtbskibjbfgzofjcvomrqorcxuq/Build/Intermediates/SimplyCircle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SimplyCircle.build/Objects-normal/i386/MessagesViewController-8AA2A9C32D34C91E.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MessagesViewController in:
    /Users/BrenoMorais/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimplyCircle-fbtbskibjbfgzofjcvomrqorcxuq/Build/Intermediates/SimplyCircle.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SimplyCircle.build/Objects-normal/i386/MessagesViewController-8AA2A9C32D34C91E.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I already know I have a duplicate object, but I do not know how to fix it.
Already I tried to give rm -rf the files to delete them.

Comment: IIRC this can be caused by importing a _.m_ file by mistake. Check all your imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking near _MessagesViewController._users

As you already now, you have duplicated objects.

Also, check this similar question: [iOS - 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941747/ios-3-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-i386)